# Python get column vector from array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of tuples (from prev processing of a structured array, but the filed info was lost).

```
>>> arr
[(0.109, 0.5), (0.109, 0.55), (0.109, 0.6)]
>>>
```

I need to extract the column vectors for first and second column.

Using two indices with fixed values works OK, but wildcarding the row fails.

```
>>> arr[0][1]
0.5
>>> arr[*][1]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    arr[*][1]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Why did you imagine "wildcarding" would work? Just a guess??? Also, are you working with an *array* or a *list*, as your output suggests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a list that contains the first element of each tuple:

```
[elem[0] for elem in arr]
```

...and the second element:

```
[elem[1] for elem in arr]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy` for this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [(0.109, 0.5), (0.109, 0.55), (0.109, 0.6)]
arr = np.array(arr)

arr[:, 1]  # array([ 0.5 ,  0.55,  0.6 ])
arr[0, :]  # array([ 0.109,  0.5  ])
```