# Extract numpy array, from np.array of tuples containing tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have seen [Python get column vector from array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716102/python-get-column-vector-from-array-of-tuples), which I expected would have answered my question, but it doesn't.

So, I've prepared an example based on an example in that post, which shows what I want to do, and where I get stuck:

```py
import numpy as np

# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716125/6197439
# arr is a numpy array of tuple "pairs" of floats

oarr = [(0.109, 0.5), (0.109, 0.55), (0.109, 0.6), (0.2, 0.4), (0.3, 0.5)]
arr = np.array(oarr)
print("arr type: {} shape: {} dt {}".format(
  type(arr), arr.shape, arr.dtype))            # arr type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (5, 2) dt float64
print("slice arr[:, 1]: {}".format(arr[:, 1])) # slice arr[:, 1]: [0.5  0.55 0.6  0.4  0.5 ]
print("slice arr[0, :]: {}".format(arr[0, :])) # slice arr[0, :]: [0.109 0.5  ]
print("arr len: {}".format(len(arr)))          # arr len: 5

# arr2, instead, becomes a numpy array of tuple "pairs", 
# with first element tuple of string and float, and second element float
# arr2 can still be sliced by numpy fine:

oarr2 = []
for ix in range(len(arr)):
  oarr2.append( ( (str(oarr[ix][0]), oarr[ix][0]), oarr[ix][1] ) )
arr2 = np.array( oarr2, dtype=object )

print("arr2 type: {} shape: {} dt {}".format(
  type(arr2), arr2.shape, arr2.dtype))           # arr2 type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (5, 2) dt object
print("slice arr2[:, 1]: {}".format(arr2[:, 1])) # slice arr2[:, 1]: [0.5 0.55 0.6 0.4 0.5]
print("slice arr2[0, :]: {}".format(arr2[0, :])) # slice arr2[0, :]: [('0.109', 0.109) 0.5]
print("arr2 len: {}".format(len(arr2)))          # arr2 len: 5

# arr2fc is where we attempt to extract the tuples in arr2 "first column",
# using numpy slicing syntax.
# arr2fc is now a numpy array of objects, as previously,
# but these objects (tuple pairs of string and float),
# are now *not* considered objects with lengths, (see .shape below)
# so extracting e.g. the first column (the string element) 
# of the tuple, with numpy slicing syntax, fails: 

arr2fc = arr2[:, 0]

print(arr2fc)                                        # [('0.109', 0.109) ('0.109', 0.109) ('0.109', 0.109) ('0.2', 0.2) ('0.3', 0.3)]
print("arr2fc type: {} shape: {} dt {}".format(
  type(arr2fc), arr2fc.shape, arr2fc.dtype))         # arr2fc type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (5,) dt object
print("slice arr2fc[:, 1]: {}".format(arr2fc[:, 1])) # IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Basically, I'd like to extract the "columns" formed by tuples in `arr2fc` as separate numpy arrays; so from the column formed by first (the string) element of this tuple, I'd like to get numpy array of object (here string):

```
[ '0.109', '0.109', '0.109', '0.2', '0.3' ]
```

... and from the column formed by second (the float) element of this tuple, I'd like to get numpy array of float:

```
[ 0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 0.2, 0.3 ]
```

Sure, I can always do a Python loop, then iterate and populate an empty Python list, then convert that to numpy array -- however, is there something like a numpy slicing syntax, that would enable me to extract these "columns" with a one-liner, avoiding Python loops?

Comment: Perhaps I am confused but why not just do `[str(x[0]) for x in oarr]` and `[x[0] for x in oarr]`?

Comment: There really should never be an array of `tuple` objects *in the first place*. There is **no way** to avoid python-level loops to interact with the objects of a `dtype=object` array. Indeed, usually if you are using `dtype=object`, you should seriously consider *just using a regular python `list` object*, since that will typically be *more performant*. Instead of using `numpy.vectorize`, which should usually be avoided, you should instead try to structure your data in a way that is amenable to numpy, in this case, using a structured array!

Comment: Thanks, @It_is_Chris - I'm just trying to simulate the types of the actual data that I have; you could say, in my actual case I get `arr2` from somewhere, and I need to extract the columns as shown.

Comment: @sdbbs perhaps you could tell us where you got this array?

Comment: Thanks for noting that @juanpa.arrivillaga - just by syntax alone, I would have thought numpy.vectorize would have outsourced looping to underlying (C?) libraries; so good to have it in mind that "there is no way to avoid python-level loops to interact with the objects of a dtype=object array".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - internal code at a company; so unfortunately, I cannot provide actual sources of the actual problem - my simulation in OP is as good as I can do in terms of demonstration.

Comment: @sdbbs so, the reason numpy is fast is because it interacts with an underlying primitive buffer of contigous, fixed-length data. Once you have `dtype=object` you *must* go into the Python layer, the buffer just contains PyObject pointers, so you lose locality of reference and must interact with these objects via their Python API. It's an escape valve that exists but should be avoided if possible

Comment: @sdbbs I don't mean the *actual* sources, I mean, what kind of process produces it? It *looks* like something that might come from a `pandas.DataFrame.values`. Of course, `pandas` fundamentally suffers from the same problem with `dtype=object`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga - you raise great points, feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept is, as I explicitly ask about avoiding Python loops - "cannot avoid" is a good answer (and with that in mind, I like np.vectorize syntax too for readability). As far as process, I'm given some files and a library, and told which function to use to open files, and the data given back as that resembles `arr2`. It might use Pandas internally, but I don't want to put too much effort in analyzing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you might want to use numpy [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). With numpy vectorize you can "vectorize" a function so that it can be applied on an input array and produce a new array or a tuple of arrays. For your example that could look like

```py
vectorized_split = np.vectorize(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
string_array,float_array = vectorized_split(arr2fc)
```

It is important to note that this will not give you any numpy vectorization performance gains, as it just runs a for loop under the hood. However, when you cannot make use of numpy vectorization like in this case,  it gives you at least a compact codebase.

Comment: It is **very important to note**, this is essentially going to be a python-level for-loop

Comment: Awesome, @SimonHawe - that seems to work great! Although, yeah - good to have in mind as juanpa.arrivillaga notes, that is a python-level for loop; so I'll keep this unaccepted for a while ...

Comment: @sdbbs again, once you've used `dtype=object`, you've abandoned the efficiency of numpy, so you might as well just use a loop/list-comprehension to interact with the objects referenced by your array

Comment: Yeah, I know it is a for loop in the end, hence vectorized in quotes. Will add that to my answer to make that clear. But as we are dealing with objects it is at least the most performant in terms of code I have to type:-)

Comment: OK, also @juanpa.arrivillaga so I don't have to edit previous comments - accepted this, as now the issue with the vectorization being Python-level loops is explicitly mentioned, and I also myself appriciate the performance in terms of ease of maintaining code (typing/reading)

Answer (score 0):

Your code as displayed in `ipython`:

```
In [178]: oarr = [(0.109, 0.5), (0.109, 0.55), (0.109, 0.6), (0.2, 0.4), (0.3,0.5)]
     ...: arr = np.array(oarr)
In [179]: oarr
Out[179]: [(0.109, 0.5), (0.109, 0.55), (0.109, 0.6), (0.2, 0.4), (0.3, 0.5)]
In [180]: arr
Out[180]: 
array([[0.109, 0.5  ],
       [0.109, 0.55 ],
       [0.109, 0.6  ],
       [0.2  , 0.4  ],
       [0.3  , 0.5  ]])
```

So starting with a list of tuples, we get a 2d array, with float dtype.  A list of lists would work the same way.

Your next array:

```
In [181]: oarr2 = []
     ...: for ix in range(len(arr)):
     ...:   oarr2.append( ( (str(oarr[ix][0]), oarr[ix][0]), oarr[ix][1] ) )
     ...: arr2 = np.array( oarr2, dtype=object )
In [182]: oarr2
Out[182]: 
[(('0.109', 0.109), 0.5),
 (('0.109', 0.109), 0.55),
 (('0.109', 0.109), 0.6),
 (('0.2', 0.2), 0.4),
 (('0.3', 0.3), 0.5)]
In [183]: arr2
Out[183]: 
array([[('0.109', 0.109), 0.5],
       [('0.109', 0.109), 0.55],
       [('0.109', 0.109), 0.6],
       [('0.2', 0.2), 0.4],
       [('0.3', 0.3), 0.5]], dtype=object)
```

Again a 2d list, (5,2), but with a tuple as one element in each row.

Selecting a column:

```
In [184]: arr2fc = arr2[:, 0]
In [185]: arr2fc
Out[185]: 
array([('0.109', 0.109), ('0.109', 0.109), ('0.109', 0.109), ('0.2', 0.2),
       ('0.3', 0.3)], dtype=object)
In [186]: _.shape
Out[186]: (5,)
```

A 1d array of objects - each a tuple.

Converting it back to list, we can make a 2d array and again index a column:

```
In [187]: arr2fc.tolist()
Out[187]: 
[('0.109', 0.109),
 ('0.109', 0.109),
 ('0.109', 0.109),
 ('0.2', 0.2),
 ('0.3', 0.3)]
In [188]: np.array(arr2fc.tolist(),object)
Out[188]: 
array([['0.109', 0.109],
       ['0.109', 0.109],
       ['0.109', 0.109],
       ['0.2', 0.2],
       ['0.3', 0.3]], dtype=object)
In [189]: _[:,1]
Out[189]: array([0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 0.2, 0.3], dtype=object)
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
In [190]: [x[1] for x in arr2fc]
Out[190]: [0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Multidimensional indexing only works on the dimensions shown by the `shape`.  It does not "reach through" and index the objects, even if they are, by themselves, indexable.

Some comparative times:

```
In [194]: timeit string_array,float_array = vectorized_split(arr2fc)
31.5 µs ± 277 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [195]: timeit [x[1] for x in arr2fc]
1.57 µs ± 1.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [196]: timeit np.array(arr2fc.tolist(),object)[:,1]
3.77 µs ± 65 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Here the "vectorize" method is much slower.  For large arrays, "vectorize" speeds are closer to the list comprehension speeds.